# jquery draggable doesn't allow drag clone images

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drop an image in a div, to create images clones inside that div whose id is *cesta*, but I get only the forbidden symbol.

HTML

```
<div id='productos' >
   <h3>PRODUCTOS</h3>
   <img id='ali-12' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_139.jpg' />
   <img id='mon-23' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_132.jpg' />
   <img id='zap-32' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_135.jpg' />
   <img id='gua-21' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_102.jpg' />
   <img id='rod-11' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_136.jpg' />
   <img id='maz-44' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_137.jpg' />
   <img id='lla-97' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_138.jpg' />
   <img id='par-10' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_126.jpg' />
   <img id='cru-24' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_121.jpg' />
   <img id='gaf-15' name='serv' class='productos' src='img/objects_131.jpg' />
</div>
<div id='cesta'>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".productos").draggable({helper:'clone'});  
    $("#cesta").droppable({
        accept: ".productos",
        drop: function(event,ui){
                $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/gaVb7/

Comment: @roasted Firefox last version

Comment: This works for me under firefox v20.0.1: http://jsfiddle.net/Cz649/

Comment: @roasted I tried it in google chrome version 26.0.1410.64 m too, and not working

Comment: Are you able to drag image inside #cesta div? Are you looking for drag image after being dropped or what? BTW, not working doesn't give much info about your problem

Comment: @jal I'm just wondering, did you include the jquery-ui script? If so, may I clarify that you only want the original images to be draggable, not the cloned one?

Comment: Solved: I didn't include <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>. My silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working fine. I tried this and is working perfect.

All i did other than what you pasted is :

1) Added 2 libs

2) Added some css

The JS code is same as yours.

```
<script src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery_ui.js"></script>

<div id='productos' >
   <h3>PRODUCTOS</h3>
   <img id='ali-12' name='serv' class='productos' src='n-2.png' />
   <img id='mon-23' name='serv' class='productos' src='n-3.png' />
   <img id='zap-32' name='serv' class='productos' src='n-4.png' />
   <img id='gua-21' name='serv' class='productos' src='n-5.png' />
   <img id='rod-11' name='serv' class='productos' src='n-6.png' />
   <img id='maz-44' name='serv' class='productos' src='n-7.png' />
</div>
<div id='cesta'>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".productos").draggable({helper:'clone'});  
$("#cesta").droppable({
    accept: ".productos",
    drop: function(event,ui){
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/janakshah89/sSRXk/1/